# Jquery date picker pop up alignment issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using JQuery date picker to select date which will be associate with a text box(I have multiple textboxes with date picker, which will be displayed using for loop).Whenever I am clicking on Date picker , that date picker pop up is not displaying beside the text box, rather it is displaying on other position(top of page).

I am facing this problem in IE and it is working fine in Mozilla. I am using IE9 and jQuery1.10.2.

Attached the scrrenshot in IE, date picker is displaying on top of text box.

Please help me to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker has absolute positioning that depends on the relative positioning of its parent. Its a CSS issue I think. 
One thing you can do is to check if the position rule of the css classes in datepicker div are not override by your css. 
The parent holder of the datepicker has to always be in `position: relative` and the datepicker itself has to be in `position:absolute`.

Comment: I have tried by making date picker position: relative and parent(in my case it is textbox) position: relative. But it has not resolved my problem. Please suggest me if any thing else.

Comment: The datepicker would actually reside out of the div where the text box is. If you would look in Firebug's HTML tab you would see its outside. The way it works is the datepicker would position itself relative to the the outermost element, probobly HTML or BODY tag, and would calculate the relative top and right value of the textbox. If there is a 'position: relative' rule given to any element parent to the textbox then its top and right values would change and datepicker would show up out of place. I think this is a CSS issue and you'd have to debug it in your design.